# Dynamic multi-diemnsional array sorting

Tags: php, arrays

Hello everyone I have a simple question. How to choose by string which column of multidimensional array to sort. Here is some informations you should know.

I have table with eshops data and a function which shows me orders for particular eshop like this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM eshops WHERE active = 1");
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
   $res = showOrders($data['host'],$data['user'],$data['pass'],$data['db'],$data['prefix']);
   echo $res;
}
```

This was my first try how to show all orders i made filters by passing sql condition to my function. But then i wanted to sort the result, and Here comes the problem i can sort every eshop but i want to sort all eshops at once it means that if i sort them by order date the eshops mix up but that is not possible right now so i made this.

Example:

```
$GLOBALS['container'] = array();
```

and in a function i put datas to array like this

```
  $GLOBALS['container'][] = array($data['eshop_id'],$data2['order_id']
  ,$data2['order_status'],$data2['order_number'],$data2['d_f_name'],$data2['d_l_name']
  ,$data2['order_total'],$data2['payment_method_id'],$data2['shipping_method_id']
  ,$data2['Exportovano'],$data2['C_Baliku'],date("d.m.Y",strtotime($data2['order_date'])));
```

Then i sort i like that

```
foreach($GLOBALS['container'] as $key => $datas){
    $eshop_id[$key] = $datas[0]; 
    $order_id[$key] = $datas[1];
    $order_st[$key] = $datas[2];
    $order_nm[$key] = $datas[3];
    $d_f_name[$key] = $datas[4];
    $d_l_name[$key] = $datas[5];
    $order_tl[$key] = $datas[6];
    $pay_m_id[$key] = $datas[7];
    $shp_m_id[$key] = $datas[8];
    $exported[$key] = $datas[9];
    $parc_num[$key] = $datas[10];
    $ord_date[$key] = $datas[11];
}

array_multisort($ord_date, SORT_DESC,$d_f_name, SORT_ASC, $GLOBALS['container']);
```

Here we go now i can sort as i wish then by foreach container select order by order also adding a condition but how to choose what i want to sort? P.e. i pass data by get

```
?sort=ord_date&orn=asc
```

I want sort ord_date variable ascending how? PLease help me thanks.

I am also open for other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier to write in SQL query, just after WHERE statement use a ORDERED BY (column) statement.
EDIT:
[Using ORDER BY statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)